# Reservoir tank is overflowing on my 2000 Pontiac Grand Am

Tags: cooling-system

I took the car down to have the radiator flushed but the mechanics refused to do it because they say I have a couple of leaks in the head gasket and intake valve gasket.

First off, what is the intake valve gasket and where is this located?

Second, the temperature in the car gets a little over 200 during the warm months but not even close to 140 during the winter months.

Third, the reservoir tank overflows. I checked the hoses to the radiator and they are flexible. Problem is, I can squeeze them and it sounds like air being pumped into the reservoir. Does this mean that the thermostat is not working properly or not?

Finally, I have seen some oil in the reservoir tank. What is the sign for that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what an "*intake valve gasket*" is. An intake gasket? Yes. The intake gasket is used to seal the union between the intake manifold and the cylinder head of the engine.

Your description of what is happening likely confirms what the mechanics told you. Bad head gaskets can allow compressed air from the cylinders into the cooling system. Hence, the air bubbles entering the reservoir and its overflowing from being over pressurized from combustion gasses.

Lastly, oil in the reservoir is also an indication of possible bad head gaskets and/or other things.

You will need to have the problem resolved to avoid engine damage, including having the cooling system flushed to remove contaminates.